# Why does Xcode define _LIBCPP_HAS_NO_ASAN when creating an address-sanitized build?

Tags: c++, address-sanitizer

Xcode 7 allows address sanitizer to be used to find memory issues in C/C++.

https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer

Turning on address sanitizer passes the compile and linker flag `-fsanitize=address` and also defines `_LIBCPP_HAS_NO_ASAN`.

When building my library from the command line and running tests on a sanitized build without defining `_LIBCPP_HAS_NO_ASAN` I see non-repeatable address-sanitizer-reported memory access issues. Defining `_LIBCPP_HAS_NO_ASAN`, as Xcode does, gets rid of the sanitizer issues but I'm curious as to why it needs doing.

Why do I need to define `_LIBCPP_HAS_NO_ASAN` with AppleClang7 to avoid getting memory access issues in libcxx?

Comment: Are you sure it's defining `_LIBCXX_HAS_NO_ASAN`?

All the libc++-specific flags start with `_LIBCPP` (not CXX)

Comment: It is _LIBCPP_HAS_NO_ASAN. Thanks Marshall. Question updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From discussion with Sean McBride (who is not on StackOverflow) there are known issues with spurious memory-out-of-bounds errors when mixing instrumented and non-instrumented code:

From Anna Zaks on http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2016/Jan/msg00077.html:

"Generally, one does not need to rebuild any code that is being linked into sanitized code."

"However, there is one corner case in C++ container overflow checking, where this might not always hold. Specifically, if libc++ containers cross from instrumented (rebuilt with ASan) to non-instrumented code, Address Sanitizer might report container overflow false positives. (Imagine two libraries, both using the same std::vector, only one of them is instrumented. Push_back from the non-instrumented module will not mark the memory for the newly added element as valid. Accessing the element from the instrumented code, would trigger a false positive report.)"

I hope this question helps someone else as this problem has consumed a considerable amount of my time. Asan is great but this info was hard to find.