# Why does an address sanitized build of a C++ library give non-reproducible ASAN issues in libcxx classes?

Tags: c++, libc++, address-sanitizer

When building with -fsanitize=address I sometimes see bad memory access issues from libc++ classes.

The errors do not appear to be repeatable from run-to-run and sometimes do not happen at all.

What is happening? How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"If libc++ containers cross from instrumented (rebuilt with ASan) to non-instrumented code, Address Sanitizer might report container overflow false positives."

If your program is linking with libraries built with libc++ without ASAN then you need to define `_LIBCXX_HAS_NO_ASAN` when building.

See [Why does Xcode define _LIBCPP_HAS_NO_ASAN when creating an address-sanitized build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38723374/why-does-xcode-define-libcpp-has-no-asan-when-creating-an-address-sanitized-bui)

Comment: Also, your own code may be the cause - if you access a vector out of boundaries the problem may be reported in `std::vector::operator[]`, but the actual culprit is the caller, which is responsible for doing his own bounds checking.

Comment: True, I'd expect that to be repeatable from run-to run though.